# bounded convergence in $L^2$ and $\mathcal{D}'$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

Show that a sequence $(f_n)_n$, that is uniformly bounded in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and converges in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$, converges weakly in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Consider $M > 0$ such that $\| f_n\|_{L^2} \leq M$ for all $n$. Let $g$ be in $L^2$ and $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c$. Then

\begin{align}
| \langle f_n , g \rangle - \langle f , g \rangle | 
&\leq |\langle f_n, g \rangle - \langle  f_n, h \rangle + \langle f_n, h \rangle - \langle f, h \rangle + \langle f, h \rangle - \langle f, g \rangle | \\
&\leq | \langle f_n, g-h \rangle + \langle f_N - f, h \rangle + \langle f, h-g \rangle| \\
 &\leq \|f_n \|_{L^2} \| g-h\|_{L^2} + \epsilon + \|f \|_{L^2}\|h-g \|_{L^2}\\
&\leq (M + \|f \|_{L^2}) \| g-h\|_{L^2} + \epsilon \\
& \leq \epsilon + \epsilon \\
& \leq 2 \epsilon 
\end{align}

Thus $\langle f_n, g \rangle \to \langle f, g \rangle$. So $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ in $L^2$. Is this correct or is there missing something? Do I need to show that $f$ is in $L^2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simpler argument: Since $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is reflexive, bounded sequences have a weakly convergent subsequence. Denote any such subsequence by $f_{n_k}$ and its limit by $f_* \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Since $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $D'(\mathbb{R})$ we must have $f_*=f$. Now since the limit is unique the whole sequence $f_n$ must converge to $f$ weakly in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Edit (slightly more detailed explanation): We know $f_{n_k}$ converges weakly to $f_* \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$. Furthermore, we also know $f_{n_k}$ converges to $f$  in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb{R})$, since it is just a subsequence of the original sequence.

Additionally, since weak convergence in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ implies convergence in the sense of distributions, we also know that $f_{n_k}$ converges to $f_*$ in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb{R})$. Since $\mathcal D'(\mathbb{R})$ is Hausdorff, limits of sequences are unique and so we must have $f=f_*$.

Comment: Thanks! So I have to show that $f$ is in $L^2$? I don’t really see why

Comment: No you get that $f$ is in $L^2$ for free because it is equal to $f_*$ which is the weak limit of a sequence in $L^2$ and so it must be in $L^2$ itself.

Comment: Ok so why if $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $D'(\mathbb{R})$ we must have that $f_*=f$?

Comment: @vitalmath I have edited my answer to explain this in more detail. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Ok! I think the sentence "weak convergence in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ implies convergence in the sense of distributions" was missing in my reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.